# How do I return a two dimentional array from a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In my below sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int *find_degree(int *triangles, int m) {


    int set[m * 3][2];
    // do some stuff here and store some values in a two dimentional array called set

    }

    return set;//I think it is not the right way to do 

}

int create_ploc(int *triangles, int m) {



    int *set;

    // trouble here , can not return the two dimentional array here from find_degree function
    set= find_degree(triangles,m);


    return 1;
}

int main() {

    int point[6][3];

    point[0][0] = 2;
    point[0][1] = 4;
    point[0][2] = 6;

    point[1][0] = 4;
    point[1][1] = 2;
    point[1][2] = 3;

    point[2][0] = 1;
    point[2][1] = 3;
    point[2][2] = 6;

    point[3][0] = 2;
    point[3][1] = 4;
    point[3][2] = 1;

    point[4][0] = 8;
    point[4][1] = 6;
    point[4][2] = 7;

    point[5][0] = 2;
    point[5][1] = 7;
    point[5][2] = 3;

    create_ploc(point, 6);

}
```

I am trying to return the address of a two dimentional array from find_degree function , but seems like this is not the right way to do. Any suggestion how could return the address of 2d array from find_degree function?

Comment: You can't return a local array. Use `malloc()` to allocate it dynamically, and return the pointer.

Comment: Try to build it, then read the errors.

Comment: To help you out some more, your problem is the variables [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#C)

Comment: `int (*find_degree(int (*triangles)[3], int m))[3]{ int (*set)[3] = calloc(m, sizeof(*set));... return set;}`... `int (*set)[3] = find_degree(triangles, m);`